# how to get the xth element from a liste by select

Tags: postgresql, select

I write like this `select alldp[1] from mytable;` it shows that

> "ERROR:  cannot subscript type text because it is not an array"

I write like this `select (string_to_array(numebe, ','))[1] from mytable`
it is still wrong.
What should I do?

```
alldp:char varying
k45
r52
f56
d36
```

Comment: Please show us your table definition, some sample data (ideally as `create table` and `insert` statements) and the expected output based on that sample data

Answer (score 0):

You're not being clear about the nature of your table, so I'll just assume you have something like this:

```
 Index | Value
____________________
   0   |  some value
   1   |  next value
  ...  |  ...
```

A select statement to get a value at a certain index would look like this:

`SELECT Value from table WHERE Index = 1`
Edit: You should refactor your table, but here's the solution you wanted...
`SELECT(SELECT string_to_array((SELECT alldp FROM myTable), ','))[1];` 
This is really resource intensive.

Comment: but I don't set up index on the row, my row alldp:g54,h54,j69,s63 I want to get the fisrt element of the row .how should I do,Thank you